# Passing GET parameters through htaccess + Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am using CodeIgniter Framework with this `.htaccess` command for "nice urls".

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

All URLs, for e.g.:

- `example.com/admin/xxx/`
- passed as -> `example.com/index.php?admin/xxx/` (look like CodeIgniter's `?/class/method/`)

But question is: How can I pass `$_GET` paramaters? For Example:

- `example.com/admin/xxx/?action=die&amp;time=now`

I need use `GET` params od external ajax scripts (f.e.: ElFinder based on CODEIGNTER)

Thanks for advices

**Edit:** 
I solved this problem just using POST method at Elfinder:
[Elfinder - Request type](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#requestType)
But btw using $_GET params in codeigniter with mark "?" with this .htaccess, is impossible

Comment: Checkout CodeIgniter's [`Input` class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) and the `$config['allow_get_array]` setting in your config file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read through the CodeIgniter documentation on [URI segments](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)?

It explains how you *could* pass through your `action` and `time` parameters.

For example `example.com/admin/xxx/die/now` would match up to the `Controller`

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function xxx($action, $time) {
        // Stuff
    }

}
```

Alternatively as @War10ck suggested you could Use the [`Input`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) class to get the required `$_GET` parameters. e.g.

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function xxx() {

        $action = $this->input->get('action');
        $time = $this->input->get('time');

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes accessing to GET params is OK, but htaccess redirect is fired earlier and redirect me to page without $_GET paramters.