# Redirect to file passing url as a parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I have a task that's been giving me considerable trouble. Any help much appreciated.

I am using an MVC framework in PHP (codeigniter) and all requests are sent through a root index.php file.

I am trying to pass another site's url as a parameter to the defualt controller. Like this:

http://mywebsite.org/https://google.com

Apparently this can be done using with a mod_rewrite rule in the root .htaccess file

so ideally i would be able to use the 'http://google.com' as a parameter in my controller.

it requires some regexp and rewriteRule knowledge. Been struggling for a while.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `http://mywebsite.org/?url=https://google.com`

Comment: good question. i am wanting users to enter it as described

Answer (score 0):

This would be a rewrite rule for the .htaccess:

`RewriteRule /(.+) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA]`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

---

With `codeigniter` this should do the job:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=uri%20segments

> The segments in the URL, in following with the Model-View-Controller approach, usually represent: **example.com/class/function/ID**

1. The first segment represents the controller class that should be
   invoked.
2. The second segment represents the class function, or
   method, that should be called.
3. The third, and any additional
   segments, represent the ID and any variables that will be passed to
   the controller.

And here is explained how:
[Passing GET parameters through htaccess + Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851074/passing-get-parameters-through-htaccess-codeigniter)

Comment: Hi Stefan. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. A great answer.